# How to interface arduino-nano with Blender?

Tags: python, arduino, accelerometer, blender

I want to control a hand model in Blender using accelerometer data through arduino nano. Serial data is received using arduino IDE. Baud Rate is 38400. 4 accelerometer are interfaced in spi with arduino nano.

Can anybody help me in scripting and interfacing of accelerometer with Blender?

Comment: Looks like someone else has done something similar: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?236135-Arduino-controls-Blender-object-in-real-time